# How to query a variable in another running application in c#?

Tags: c#, shared-memory

I have an app that, when launched, checks for duplicate processes of itself.

That part I have right - but what I need is to check a state variable in the original running process in order to run some logic.

So: how do I make a variable (e.g. bool) available publicly to other applications so they can query it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. A very primative way would be to read/write from a file. The old win32 way would be to use [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx). The more .NET way would be to use remoting or WCF and [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365590(VS.85).aspx).

.NET 4 is also getting support for [Memory Mapped files](http://blogs.msdn.com/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx).

Here is a pretty thorough looking artcile describing a few different approaches including support for Memory Mapped files outside of .NET 4 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/csthreadmsg.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest: Create a file, and write something in it.

More advanced, and when done correctly more robust, is using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119.aspx), you use named pipes to setup some communication channel on the local computer only.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1(VS.80).aspx) to check whether another process is running (you should be) you could use another Mutex whose locked state would be the boolean flag you're looking.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is to use the Windows API to create and lock a mutex. The first app to open will create and lock the mutex. Any subsequent executions of the app will not be able to get it and can then shutdown.